# Checking CBPeripheralManager.authorizationStatus() now that it is deprecated

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

`CBPeripheralManager.authorizationStatus()` and `CBPeripheralManagerAuthorizationStatus` are deprecated based on apple docs. What is the proper way of checking whether user has granted permission to use bluetooth in background now?

`CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` has `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState` but that never returns `unauthorized` regardless of whether user granted the permission or not, instead it only returns `poweredOn` or `poweredOff`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheralManager` inherit from [`CBManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmanager).

As of iOS 13, `CBManager` has an [`authorization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmanager/3180033-authorization?changes=latest_minor) property.  You can check this for `.allowedAlways`.

You can use `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)` to conditionally use `authorization` on iOS 13 and later

Comment: There is no request authorization method. Can I request Core Bluetooth authorization in any way?

Comment: Your app automatically requests Bluetooth permission when it instantiates a `CBCentralManager` instance

Comment: Ok I see I have this pop-up but then i always get error "Blueooth is not powerd on." In spite of it is turned on.

Comment: Where do you get that error?  In the `didUpdateState` callback?  Perhaps you should [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) including relevant code and a screen shot if relevant.

Comment: in didUpdateState I get .poweredOn, but then I am using nearable stickers from Estimote and from there I have returned bluetooth is powered off. I have separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58137280/ios-13-estimote-sdk-beacon-ranging

Answer (score 7):

Please note that Apple changed the `CBManager` API between 13.0 and 13.1

- In 13.0 `authorization` is an instance property.
- In 13.1 `authorization` is a type (class) property.

The 13.0 instance property [has been marked as deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmanager/3180033-authorization?changes=latest_major&language=objc).