# Xamarin iOS 13 check bluetooth permission without triggering a native popup

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, permissions, ios13

iOS 13 started to request Bluetooth permission. When bluetooth permission isn't granted yet, I want to show a custom screen to explain why I need the Bluetooth and suggest to give the app an access to it. Before that I have to check if bluetooth permission is granted or not.

This function immediately shows native popup and asks for the permission:

```cs
public bool NeedsBluetoothPermission()
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
            {
                return CBCentralManager.Authorization != CBManagerAuthorization.AllowedAlways;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**Question**: How to check if the app needs to request bluetooth permissions without triggering native popup first?

[This answer](/questions/57851959/how-to-control-when-to-present-the-bluetooth-permission-request-prompt-in-ios13) doesn't work for me, as I don't create any instance of CBCentralManager yet, I only use its static property.

Native iOS developers, please chime in too. I guess it's not Xamarin problem only...

Comment: You can write your explanation in the `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` key in the `info.plist`. If `CBCentralManager.Authorization` is the only way to check bluetooth   permission, I think you can't show a custom screen before use it. You can also choose to show the custom screen when people finished install the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured this out.
This behavior was actual for iOS 13.0 beta.

For the latest iOS 13.2 I don't observe this issue.

I'm able to check CBCentralManager.Authorization property silently.
The system pop-up shows up when I create an instance of CBCentralManager.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was actually not a beta issue but an actual iOS 13.0 bug and it was fixed in iOS 13.1. Hopefully since iOS 13.1 was release 7 days after 13.0, a very small number of people should be on iOS 13.0. [Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57052098/checking-cbperipheralmanager-authorizationstatus-now-that-it-is-deprecated/58767116#58767116)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use CBCentralInitOptions, where you can set "ShowPowerAlert" as false.

When you create the instance of CBCentralManager, pass the init option and it won't show a native popup

Answer (score 0):

In my case, CBCentralManager.Authorization does not exist. But CBPeripheralManager.authorization is a static class var that works with iOS 13+. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager)

```
- (void)checkBluetoothPermissionStatus:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    if (@available(iOS 13.1, *)) {
        switch(CBPeripheralManager.authorization) {
            case CBPeripheralManagerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                NSLog(@"CBP BLE allowedAlways");
                [self requestBluetoothPermission: command]; // Further get the BLE on/off status once the permission is granted
                break;
            case CBPeripheralManagerAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                NSLog(@"CBP BLE denied");
                [self sendMessage:@"Denied" error:true command:command];
                break;
            case CBPeripheralManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                NSLog(@"CBP BLE notDetermined");
                [self sendMessage:@"Undetermined" error:true command:command];
                break;
            case CBPeripheralManagerAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                NSLog(@"CBP BLE restricted");
                [self sendMessage:@"Restricted" error:true command:command];
                break;
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        NSLog(@"CBP BLE unknown");
        [self sendMessage:@"Unknown" error:true command:command];
    }
}
```